# Silverlight Control Toolkit TreeView not rendering items

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, xaml

I'm trying to build a SL app with a TreeView in it.  Here's my XAML:

```
<UserControl xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit"
             xmlns:tkwin="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit"
             xmlns:basics="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"             
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="SL.MyApp.Page"
    Width="800" Height="600">
    <controls:DockPanel>        
        <controls:TreeView Name="siteTree" controls:DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="150">
            <controls:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <tkwin:HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                        
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </tkwin:HierarchicalDataTemplate>   
            </controls:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </controls:TreeView> 
        <basics:TabControl controls:DockPanel.Dock="Right" TabStripPlacement="Top">
            <basics:TabItem Header="Sites"></basics:TabItem>
            <basics:TabItem Header="Lists"></basics:TabItem>
            <basics:TabItem Header="Users"></basics:TabItem>
        </basics:TabControl>      
    </controls:DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

And the relevant codebehind:

```
namespace SL.MyApp
{
    public partial class Page : UserControl
    {
        private ObservableCollection<WebDescriptor> _webHierarchy = new ObservableCollection<WebDescriptor>(); 

        public Page(WebsSvc.WebsSoapClient websClient)
        {           
            InitializeComponent();

            siteTree.ItemsSource = _webHierarchy;

            websClient.GetWebCollectionCompleted 
                += new EventHandler<SL.SiteBuilder.WebsSvc.GetWebCollectionCompletedEventArgs>(websClient_GetWebCollectionCompleted);
            websClient.GetWebCollectionAsync();

            // TODO: some kind of spinner or progress bar needs to be started.
        }

        void websClient_GetWebCollectionCompleted(object sender, SL.SiteBuilder.WebsSvc.GetWebCollectionCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (XElement xe in e.Result.Elements())
            {
                _webHierarchy.Add(ServiceObjectParser<WebDescriptor>.Parse(xe));
            }
        }      
    }
}
```

Update:  The WebDescriptor class:

```
public class WebDescriptor
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public List<WebDescriptor> Children { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is that nothing renders in the TreeView at all.  I have verified that the results obtained in websClient_GetWebCollectionCompleted are valid and correct, but....nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post more information about what your web service is returning?

Comment: I've added the WebDescriptor class definition.  The service returns XML data (note the foreach line), which is parsed by the ServiceObjectParser class.  The service itself really isn't important, as long as the WebDescriptor objects are created correctly, and they are.

Comment: I had to edit my answer about 5 times, but try those.  It seems as though you are trying to bind your textblock to a nonexistent property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the binding trace output, I finally realized I was trying to bind to a field instead of a property.

Doh!

Answer (score 0):

in websClient_GetWebCollectionCompleted:

siteTree.ItemsSource = _webHierarchy;

Also, change your binding on the TextBlock in the Treeview to be {Binding Title}